# Closed form solution for Helmholtz equation $(\Delta + 1) p(x) = 0$ in free space?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, bessel-functions, wave-equation

Consider the Helmholtz equation

$$(\Delta + 1) p(x) = 0 \quad \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^2$$

with the Sommerfield radiation condition applying to $p$. That is,

$$\lim_{|x| \to \infty} \bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial |x|} - i \bigg) p(x) = 0.$$

Is a straightforward closed form analytic solution possible for this problem?

Comment: Could you also provide the radiation condition? Thanks.

Comment: @JackyChong I have added the radiation condition.